# Selenium C# How to handle Alert "Open Pick an app"?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, alert, ui-testing

I am trying to get the Alert's Text using Selenium C# for Chrome

[image]

But this alert seems different from a normal JavaScript Alert, using the code below returns an error exception:

```
string text = driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;
```

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert

Is this considered as an alert? Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog you're seeing is shown on the OS level so there's no way for you to see that in the DOM or use Selenium to interact with it. If you really need to deal with it, I'd suggest you look into an OS-level automation tool that could send key or mouse events to handle the dialog in a way you need to.

With Java, you would be fine using the [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class defined in the Java AWT package, as it's meant exactly for dealing with native input events associated with test automation and is often referred to when dealing with Selenium and dialogs. However, it doesn't exist in the .NET world so you need to look elsewhere. A quick Google search gave me something that might help:

[Robot Framework](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework) (Supports .NET by using IronPython)

Also, you could do it even simpler with something like this:

[GlobalMouseKeyHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)

So, to summarize. No, it's not a normal Alert as you expect it to be and yes, you can handle it but it requires some steps outside the Selenium world.

Comment: Too bad there isn't for .Net, thank you for the frameworks recommendations.

Comment: No problem, I hope that you manage to solve the issue. My advice would be to try to avoid this situation altogether if possible.

Comment: You could use AutoIT. It is a nuget package and will allow you to interact with Windows Objects.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Dazed. I wasn't aware that there's an actual NuGet package of AutoIT.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below windows forms sendkeys code to accept the OS level popups

```
 System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}");
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```