# How to edit a not selenium default alert pop-up in selenium/python? no such alert problem

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, popup

I have a big problem with the pop-up window, which is clearly not a default alert message in selenium. I've searched everything but there is no solution for the selenium and Python problem. I ask for help. I want to edit and click the following popup.

[image: This pop up is not selenium alert]

```
driver.switch_to.alert() does not work. As I said, it is not a selenium alert.
```

This is `error` which shows up when I'm using:

> driver.switch_to.alert : selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert

Comment: I searched, and I found that, I hope to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154160/how-to-click-on-open-application-alert-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `--disable-default-apps` when starting up Chrome?

Comment: This answer could be a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where should i put your code in my code? Have you an example?

Comment: I do not have an example at the moment, but you can get some inspiration from here:
https://itecnote.com/tecnote/python-how-to-override-default-set-of-chrome-command-line-switches-in-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

This is the soluton to click on left button! You need to install the pynput module!

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

    keyboard = Controller()
    keyboard.press(Key.left)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
```