# How to close a Telegram popup using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

When I click on the link in the Telegram, a window appears

[image: Photo of problem]

---

How do I press the "Отмена" button using selenium?

I tried to solve the problem with 'selenium alert' but nothing works

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://t.me/rian_ru')

time.sleep(2)

try:
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("alert accepted")
except:
    print("no alert")
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and reading for a long time, I finally found a way to bypass that confirmation using **Selenium 4.9**.

All the [*duplicate* questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154160/how-to-click-on-open-application-alert-using-selenium) are outdated, or simply wrong at all!

---

The reason why `driver.switch_to.alert` doesn't work is because it's a OS alert, not a Chromium `alert()`.

---

You can pass a chrome option that will allow some protocols on a specific url

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "protocol_handler": {
        "allowed_origin_protocol_pairs": {
            "https://t.me": { "tg": True }
        }
    }
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(FILL_THIS_YOURSELF, options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://t.me/some-fancy-user-name')
```

This tells Chromium to allow 'tg://' protocols to be handled on `https://t.me` websites, without any confirmation.